# NVEnc Directshow Filter [NVIDIA VIDEO ENCODER FILTER]

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, directshow, nvenc

I could successfully use h264_nvenc in ffmpeg to record my video source using nVidia.
But I need Pause/Resume the recording.
Which seems not possible with ffmpeg.
Suspend ffmpeg process pause the video frame but file continues.

So I need a directshow filter with h.264 nvenc support to use in my application.
I need .ax or .dll directshow filter to test in graphedit.
I couldn't anything on the net.
Could some expert help me to get a directshow filter or some clue ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421869/H-264-CUDA-Encoder-DirectShow-Filter-in-Csharp

That seems to be a DirectShow filter built with C# which encodes H.264 using NVIDIA CUDA API.